# How to Hide and Show the Form from ALT + TAB

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to show my form when a hot key is pressed(Already Done).
When I close that I am using this.opacity = 0. But it is still appearing in ALT + TAB.
So How should I hide it and show too

Comment: There's a property called `ShowInTaskbar` or similar that you can set to `false` to hide the window from ALT+TAB (and from the taskbar)

Comment: You mean `this.Hide()`. You're not *closing* the Form, you're just trying to make it *invisible*. If you hide it, it won't appear in the ALT+TAB selection. -- That's too simple. Why aren't you hiding the Form in the first place? Is something missing here? Doesn't the Form go to the Tray Notification Area?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Guyz,
I figured it out my self.

When You want to hide the form

```
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow;
this.Opacity = 0;
this.Hide();
```

When you want to show the form

```
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
this.Opacity = 1;
this.Show();
```